# How to add radiobutton in datatable in a shiny module?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I have the same problem already  described at this link [ckeckboxWithShinyModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118218/how-to-add-checkbox-in-datatable-in-a-shiny-module) but the column i want to add is made of radiobutton, where user can select among 3 possible value ('a', 'b, 'c').
I'm not sure how to retrieve the selected val via the JS callback. Could anyone help me to modify the js code provided in the accepted answer proposed at the previous link, in case of the edit cell is a radiobutton instead of a checkbox, also in case of multi page datatable? (known solution for checkbox reported below).  Thanks

```
js <- function(dtid, ns) {
  c(
    "$('body').on('click', '[id^=checkb]', function(){",
    "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
    "  var i = parseInt(/checkb(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
    "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
    "  var info = [{row: i, col: 3, value: value}];",
    sprintf(
      "Shiny.setInputValue('%s', info);",
      ns(sprintf("%s_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo", dtid))
    ),
    "})"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for(i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
  }
  inputs
}

dat0 <- data.frame(
  fruit  = c("apple", "cherry", "pineapple", "pear"),
  letter = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)

dat1 <- cbind(dat0, choice = "X")

choices <- list("X", "Y") # choices for the radio buttons
dat2 <- cbind(
  dat0,
  check = shinyInput(radioButtons, nrow(dat0), "radiob", choices = choices)
)

js <- function(dtid, ns) {
  c(
    "$('body').on('click', '[name^=radiob]', function() {",
    "  var name = this.getAttribute('name');",
    "  var i = parseInt(/radiob(\\d+)/.exec(name)[1]);",
    "  var value = $(this).val();",
    "  var info = [{row: i, col: 3, value: value}];",
    sprintf(
      "Shiny.setInputValue('%s', info);",
      ns(sprintf("%s_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo", dtid))
    ),
    "})"
  )
}

tableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(
      7,
      DTOutput(ns("dtable"))
    ),
    column(
      5,
      verbatimTextOutput(ns("reactiveDF"))
    )
  )
}

tableServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    Dat <- reactiveVal(dat1)
    
    output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT(
      {
        datatable(
          dat2,
          rownames = TRUE,
          escape = FALSE,
          editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = 3)),
          selection = "none",
          callback = JS(js("dtable", session$ns))
        )
      },
      server = FALSE
    )
    
    observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
      info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
      Dat(editData(Dat(), info))
    })
    
    output[["reactiveDF"]] <- renderPrint({
      Dat()
    })
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  tableUI("xxx")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tableServer("xxx")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```